# Haskell divide the sum of second element in a tuple

Tags: haskell

I've got a list of tuples, and I want to work out the average so:
(sum of all int's) / list length

The list looks like:

```
[("Student1", 1), ("Student2", 2), ("Student3", 3)]
```

so far I have a function that addes up all the 'ages' (1, 2 & 3), but I don't know how to combine that with a division of the list's length.

Function:

```
addMarks :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
addMarks list = sum . map snd / length(list)
```

Length(list) gives me 3, so if I can divide the sum function by the length I will get my average.

without lamda expressions if ya can,

Thanks!
Tom

Answer (score 2):

Use `div` function, if you want the result in `Int`. Using `/` will give a fractional result. This code should work:

```
addMarks :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
addMarks list = sum (map snd list) `div` length(list)
```

Or a more cleaner version:

```
addMarks :: [(String, Int)] -> Int
addMarks list = sum nums `div` length nums
  where nums = map snd list
```

You can also use the `/` function for solving this. You have to then use the functions like `fromIntegral` to convert them to proper types.

Comment: +1, thanks man, just what I was looking for!
I do however, want it to be a Float - because it's working out the average and the average needs to allow a decimal point.
Changing `div` to '/' gives me type error though.. Any suggestions?

Comment: Change your type signature to indicate that you want `Float` to be the output. Then use the `fromIntegral` function to convert them properly.